# Wrong gridview variable in onContextItemSelected()

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have couple pages using FragmentStatePagerAdapter, each contains GridView.
Problem is when I try to do any action using adapter (e.g. myAdapter.remove(object)) in onContextItemSelected() - this action is done by adapter from different page.
I've tried to use getUserVisibleHint() without any success.

I am confused, beacuse when item from GridView is long-cliked in method onCreateContextMenu() gridAdatper is from actual page, but in onContextItemSelected gridAdapter is from different page.

**Expected behavior:**
After long click there is inflated context menu, than by selecting item from menu list (for example delete), proper gridAdapter (from fragment on current page) handle this operation.

**Current bahaviour:**
After context menu is inflated, onContextItemSeleted holds gridAdapter from different page, so when I try to remove item from grid on page 2, item is deleted from page 1.

```
  @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        //super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info;
        try {
            // Casts the incoming data object into the type for AdapterView objects.
            info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // If the menu object can't be cast, logs an error.
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "bad menuInfo", e);
            return;
        }
        Log.d("ContextCreate", "grid adapter count " + gridAdapter.getCount() + " gridview count " + gridView.getCount());
        Scene scene =  gridAdapter.getItem(info.position);
        if (scene == null) {
            // For some reason the requested item isn't available, do nothing
            return;
        }
        menu.setHeaderTitle(scene.getLabel());
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.grid_scene_menu, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


if (getUserVisibleHint()) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int positionInGrid = info.position;
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_edit_scene:

            // get item from adapter and pass it to another class
            return true;

        case R.id.action_delete:
            gridAdapter.remove(gridAdapter.getItem(positionInGrid));
            gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
else
    return false;

    }
```

GridAdapter:

```
public class SceneGridArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Scene> {
List<Scene> sceneList;
private static final char[] alphabet= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP".toCharArray();
Context context;

boolean[] isPressed;
public SceneGridArrayAdapter(Context context, List<Scene> scenes) {
    super(context, 0, scenes);
    this.context=context;

    this.sceneList=scenes;
    isPressed= new boolean[scenes.size()];

}


@Override
public void add(Scene sceneToAdd) {
    DriversSingleton.getCurrentDriver().getConfiguration().addActiveScene(sceneToAdd);
    super.add(sceneToAdd);

 }


@Override
public void remove(Scene scene) {
    int sceneIndex=scene.getIndex();
    DriversSingleton.getCurrentDriver().getConfiguration().removeSceneAt(scene.getIndex());
    super.remove(scene);

    new CommunicationService(context).writeSceneAt(DriversSingleton.getCurrentDriver(), sceneIndex, 0xFF, 0xFF);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   final Scene scene= getItem(position);
    if (convertView==null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_layout, parent, false);
    }

    final ImageView imageBackground=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image_rect);
    TextView sceneTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.scene_label);
    TextView groupTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group);

    sceneTv.setText(scene.getLabel());
    if(scene.getGroup()<16) {
        groupTv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        groupTv.setText("Group " + alphabet[scene.getGroup()]);
    }
    else
        groupTv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);



    if(isPressed[position]==true){

        imageBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.scene_item_selected);
        isPressed[position]=true;

    }
    else if(isPressed[position]==false){

        imageBackground.setImageResource(R.drawable.scene_item);
        isPressed[position]=false;

    }


    return convertView;
}


public void setSelection (int position)
{
    if(isPressed[position]==false){

        isPressed[position]=true;

    }
    else if(isPressed[position]==true){
        isPressed[position]=false;
    }
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
public boolean isSelected (int position)
{
    return isPressed[position];
}

}
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stackoverflow! Your issue is not immediately apparent from your question. Please try to reformat or reword your initial paragraph so that it is obvious what your error is. Ideally provide clearly what you are expecting, and what you actually get.

Comment: @Knossos Thank you for your interest. I've added two paragraphs to better explain what I meant.

Comment: @Blackbelt  I've added GridAdapter, I would like to notice that when context menu is created adapter is from that fragment (page) where click event was detected, but moment after that where menu item is selected, adapter is from different page (that which inflated contextmenu for the first time.)

Comment: No I don't any header/footer view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found my bug.

It was ugly code to instatiate new pagerAdapter in onResume to refresh pager tabs order.

So to properly handle gridAdapter object using context menu and pagerView:

1. call registerForContextMenu(View v) after setting adapter.
2. give instruction on item select only to visible fragment check it by-getUserVisibleHint(), else return false.
3. Do not reinstatiate pagerAdapter each time.

Comment: Great, make sure that you accept your own answer, so that this question is completed. You may not be able to yet.